# sorting complex array

Tags: java, arrays, function, sorting

I have question in my assignment says:

> Given an unsorted array whose elements are all 0 (zeros) or 1 (ones),
>      write code to sort the array so that all the 0's appear first, followed by all the 1's.
>      You may assume that 'num_elements' always accurately indicates the number of elements
>         in the array.
>      Please use the following function header:

```
void sort_elements(int array[], int num_elements);
```

## I realy have no idea what he means by that, did he want two arrays or just one. Please explain to me.

**I did it :D I can't believe myself ,, i used 2 for loops with 2 if in it
 .. thank u all for ur assistance guys <3 <3**

```
public class Q4 {

    public static void main (String []args){

         int Sky[]={0,0,1,1,0,1};
         sort_elements(Sky,Sky.length);          
       }

      public static void  sort_elements(int array[],int num_elements){
         for ( int i=0; i < num_elements ; i++){
            if ( array[i]==0){
               System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }

         for ( int i=0; i<num_elements ; i++){
            if ( array[i]==1){
               System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: **assassinate** ??.. lol do you mean **assignment**??

Comment: One array. I don't know why you'd think two arrays would make sense, or even how they would be returned, given the method signature.

Comment: @RayToal The wikipedia link to assassination. I didn't find it that funny :(

Comment: His user name *is* "Obscure Man", after all.

Comment: *"please explain to me"*  You should be asking that of whoever assigned the task.

Comment: @Gang..etc , wrong typing , I have edited .

Comment: @ObscureMan no problomo mahn ... :)

Comment: We've all made typos - laughing _with_ you, not _at_ you. :)

Comment: it's ok guys :)
@Matt Ball , I assumed he wanted 2 arrays because in the question he said "sort the array so that all the 0's appear first, followed by all the 1's" it means there is 2 array for ones and for zeros ..

Comment: @ObscureMan Your question says you just need to use one array. the parameters you are passing is int array and number of elements in array, however you can sort that array according to your logic in sort_elements method.

Comment: @ObscureMan You are not sorting your array. you are just looking for array elements are 0 or 1 and printing them in console. your actual array having no effect at all. That means you are not sorting anything at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Maintain two pointers left and right.
2) Start traversing left pointer towards right until 1 is encountered.
3) Start right pointer towards left until 0 is encountered.
4) set array[left] = 0, array[right] = 1
5) Continue doing so until left and right pointer converge.
6) Since, we have to traverse the array only once, sorting happened in O(n) time.

Comment: This is a cute algorithm!  Swap needn't actually swap, of course, a simple `array[left] = 0, array[right] = 1` does the trick.

Comment: yeah. its not needed. I will edit the solution.

Comment: We can also use fact that there are only two kinds of elements in array (0 and 1). All we need to do is count number of zeros, then set few first elements to zero (according to our counter) and rest of elements to ones. No swapping needed and we can do it in two iterations.

Comment: @Pshemo Nice way to resolve issue.

Comment: @Pshemo, the solution presented by the answer only traverses once and is more efficient than your suggestion to count, which makes two passes.

Comment: @Pshemo I really will be very glad if u make ur solution to code :)

Comment: @ObscureMan NO one is going to do your homework for you. Try first and if you caught anywhere put the code, we will glad to help you out..

Comment: @RayToal yes I know, but since it is homework I decided to show OP other (maybe little simpler to implement) way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear from the problem statement that your function is expected to sort `array` in place.

As to actually implementing this, read up on [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Answer (score 0):

If I was implementing this, I would need only one line:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: But its a school assignment, most probably his prof told him not to use any API method :)

Comment: Also IMHO the 0s and 1s are a tip-off that counting sort is expected.

Comment: @ObscureMan API method means its already defined method in java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @smit I didn't hear abt it before :)

Comment: @ObscureMan lots of things we hear or see in life is first time. Don't get disappointed. Work hard...Follow this link to get more information about  API http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface